# Difference between Dependency Injection and @DependsOn

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, dependencies

we are using Spring in our project and today I found, in my eyes, a strange beaviour. In my opinion Dependency Injection and the annotation @DependsOn should be the same in the following both cases

```
@Bean
public ClassA classA(){
    //code
}

@Bean
public ClassB classB(ClassA classA){
    someMethodWhichNeedsClassA()
}
```

and

```
@Bean
public ClassA classA(){
    //code
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("classA")
public ClassB classB(){
    someMethodWhichNeedsClassA()
}
```

It seems, that those both ways are not identical. I am not allowed to share my code, but in the first case I have access to a list which is filled in the first Bean, but not in the second case. 
I tried to find something in the documentation or in other blogs but without success.

Has anybody an idea if there is any differences between those both ways, because I thougth it has something to do with ordering of bean creation and thats all.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What you mean by *needs* in the method *someMethodWhichNeedsClassA()*? DO you mean that this method calls *classA*? Or do you mean it needs just the results of initialization of the bean *classA*?

Answer (score 1):

Spring, by default, manages beans' lifecycle and arranges their initialization order. This is the case in your first example. While in your second example you tell Spring that bean B depends on A. So spring will create bean A before bean B.

[@DependsOn from spring docs:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html)

> Beans on which the current bean depends. Any beans specified are
>   guaranteed to be created by the container before this bean. Used
>   infrequently in cases where a bean does not explicitly depend on
>   another through properties or constructor arguments, but rather
>   depends on the side effects of another bean's initialization.

[Baeldung spring DependsOn](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on)

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. In the first case the ClassA bean should be created before ClassB since it is used in the constructor and Spring should create it because of dependency injection

Comment: Please post all the relevant code. I don't see the constructor where you use either of these classes

Comment: I am not allowed to share the code, but ClassB does not depend directely on ClassA, but it calls a methode which needs the ClassA

Answer (score 1):

In simple words there are two scenarios

1. If beans creation is in sequence, spring will start initializing from top to bottom. In this case, depending on bean needs to listed first
2. If beans creation is not in sequence and getting managed through multiple appconfig, in this we can use `@DependsOn` annotation to make sure that dependent beans are initialized before getting used.

Answer (score 0):

If bean B calls any method on bean A (or passes to some other objects/methods that eventually call methods of bean A), then dependency injection is sufficient.

Bug there are cases when bean B does not need to call any methods on bean A,
but dependsn on the result of initialization of bean A. Suppose bean A during its initialization creates tables in database,
and bean B needs these table before it can be use. Then dependency injection makes no sense. Any code quality check will show you that
injected variable is not used and thus is not needed.
In such case you don't inject bean A into B, but declare dependency on bean A.

Briefly: If bean B calls bean A, use dependency injection. If bean B only needs results of initialization of bean A, use *@DependsOn*.